# inotify don't treat vim editting as a modification event

Tags: linux, vim, inotify

my example code below watches a file for being modified. let's say the file being wathched is foo.txt, and the binary name came out from the sample code is inotify. I did two test for the sample code.

test1:
1) ./inotify foo.txt
2)  echo "hello" > foo.txt
then everything works fine,and "**file modified**" has been printed out.

test2:
1) ./infity foo.txt
2) vim foo.txt
3) edit somehow and save,but don't quit vim
the printed out line is  **unknown Mask 0x00008000**, checked out the inotify header file found this event mask mean **IN_CLOSE_WRITE**.

from my point of view, "edit and save" just menas modify. but obvisously the inotify code has a different interpration for it. it's strange for me, can anyone help to explain the things behind?

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fdnotify = -1; 

  if (argc !=2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./inotify dir_name\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("argc is %d\n", argc);

  fdnotify = inotify_init();
  if (fdnotify < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "inotity_init failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }

  int wd = inotify_add_watch(fdnotify, argv[1], IN_MODIFY);
  if (wd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "inotify_add_watch failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }

  while(1) {
    char buffer[4096];
    struct inotify_event *event = NULL;

    int len = read(fdnotify, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    if (len < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "read error %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }   

    event = (struct inotify_event *) buffer;

    while(event != NULL) {
      if ((event->mask & IN_MODIFY)  ) { 
        printf("File modified %s\n", event->name);
      } else {
 printf("unknown Mask 0x%.8x\n", event->mask);
      }
      len -= sizeof(*event) + event->len;

      if (len > 0)
        event = ((void *) event) + sizeof(event) + event->len;
      else
        event = NULL;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `inotifywait -m foo.txt` have to say about the events being generated?

Answer (score 8):

Vim is a program that does not directly save to the file while you save the file. It creates a temporary file usually named `.filename.swp` and only when you close vim this file gets renamed to `filename`. From the inotify's FAQ:

> The IN_MODIFY event is emitted on a file content change (e.g. via the write() syscall) while IN_CLOSE_WRITE occurs on closing the changed file. It means each change operation causes one IN_MODIFY event (it may occur many times during manipulations with an open file) whereas IN_CLOSE_WRITE is emitted only once (on closing the file).

So the event you get actually makes sense. Lets say that you have a file called `filename`. When you open the file `filename` another file is created named `.filename.swp`. All modifications you perform on this file would, if monitored, generate a number of `IN_MODIFY` events. When you actually save, what ends up happening is, vim renames this file and closes it, thus generating the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event.

Comment: Note that the OP says he says `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` while vim is still running. Try opening a file, saving, and leaving vim open. If you cat the file, you'll see your changes.

Comment: The swap file format for vim is not just a text copy of the file being edited.  Try `cat`ing the swap file, and you get a bunch of binary garbage, plus some of the contents of the file (seems newlines are missing?).  I think vim updates the swap file every time you finish a command, but that it actually modifies the original file directly, at least in my test case.

Comment: Writing with vim to a watching file calls `IN_IGNORED` it is because vim replaces the file and due to this the actual watch is removed.

Comment: @arcticmac is right that the `.swp` file is not the actual file (it contains some data) but to avoid data loss, all sane editors will try to write out an updated file to a new file first, then rename the new file into place. Vim in particular seems to check the link count on the file: if it has link count 1, vim will write the new updated file to a temporary name and rename. If it has link count > 1, vim will write the new data to the original file, so that the hard links are updated as well.

Comment: Original vi (from 2.9BSD and 4.xBSD) always wrote directly on the original file, which meant that when you were out of disk space, you lost your file. This was, um, bad. :-) Gosling Emacs always wrote a new file and renamed, which would break links. This too was bad. So vim uses this compromise trick.

Answer (score 2):

I thought Mask 0x00008000 was IN_IGNORED
According to inotify.h:

```
#define IN_CLOSE_WRITE   0x00000008 /* Writtable file was closed.  */
#define IN_IGNORED   0x00008000 /* File was ignored.  */
```

Is it posible that the event mask is an IN_IGNORED?

Comment: Yes it is very much possible that event mask is `In_IGNORED`